# How does one start programming/communicating with finished hardware using an Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, usb, hardware

Arduino apprentice here. I've done my fair share of basic Arduino projects, like building a thermostat and a remote-controlled/area-scanning car through Bluetooth. But all these projects rely on existing libraries.

I own a Nikon D3300 DSLR and wanted to make an intervalometer for it using the built-in usb port and my Arduino-Uno. Now I don't really know where to start like how do I figure out which pins or bits or whatever control certain things on my camera.

Having used a USB Host Shield and its [library](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) (I'm so grateful for this), I found out that a lot of 'classes' have predefined addresses or something like that.

*example from BTD.h from the [library](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/BTD.h)*

```
/* HCI Events managed */
#define EV_INQUIRY_COMPLETE                             0x01
#define EV_INQUIRY_RESULT                               0x02
#define EV_CONNECT_COMPLETE                             0x03
#define EV_INCOMING_CONNECT                             0x04
#define EV_DISCONNECT_COMPLETE                          0x05
#define EV_AUTHENTICATION_COMPLETE                      0x06
#define EV_REMOTE_NAME_COMPLETE                         0x07
#define EV_ENCRYPTION_CHANGE                            0x08
#define EV_CHANGE_CONNECTION_LINK                       0x09
#define EV_ROLE_CHANGED                                 0x12
#define EV_NUM_COMPLETE_PKT                             0x13
#define EV_PIN_CODE_REQUEST                             0x16
#define EV_LINK_KEY_REQUEST                             0x17
#define EV_LINK_KEY_NOTIFICATION                        0x18
#define EV_DATA_BUFFER_OVERFLOW                         0x1A
#define EV_MAX_SLOTS_CHANGE                             0x1B
#define EV_READ_REMOTE_VERSION_INFORMATION_COMPLETE     0x0C
#define EV_QOS_SETUP_COMPLETE                           0x0D
#define EV_COMMAND_COMPLETE                             0x0E
#define EV_COMMAND_STATUS                               0x0F
#define EV_LOOPBACK_COMMAND                             0x19
#define EV_PAGE_SCAN_REP_MODE                           0x20
```

Now I reached the limit of my Arduino skills and don't know what to do. How do I figure out how I can communicate with my camera through USB. I'd really want to try this from scratch instead of relying on a library yet again.

Comment: you want to use some libraries but not all, or you want to go full on bare metal?  usb is not remotely the first thing you want to try bare metal.  blink an led, spit stuff out the uart, can take you a week or more.  usb might take months as a fair amount is learning usb independent of the chip.  lastly hacking at a protocol for your camera, if not fully documented somewhere, is yet another research project.   so it is unclear what you are asking...

Comment: Are you sure your camera can do what you want via the USB?

Comment: FYI you can buy apps for your phone which have this functionality (and a lot more).

Comment: @dwelch well my goal is to make an intervalometer myself if the best way is to use a library (if it exists) then so be it. Secondly if I want to write my own library or own specific code to control camera features like shutterspeed etc, how do I figure out what values or whatever I have to send out to my camera through the usb (lets say I'll still be using the usb host library as a basis)

Comment: @Blurry Sterk there are numerous existing projects on YouTube but the majority don't give away any code so I can't figure out how they did it

Comment: @Edward Wow, just a noobish thing :P Anyway, when you have to interface with something you don't have a library for, you should know how to do it yourself. Usually for common hardware you have a datasheet explaining the protocol, but for this kind of product I hardly believe there is the USB description. You can try asking Nikon, but I don't think they will be interested. The last hope is to find the linux generic driver which controls the camera and look at its source code (the linux drivers embedded in the kernel are open source)

Comment: @frarugi so basically it's close to impossible for someone like me

Comment: @Edward even for me... And for a lot of people here ;) you can try searching for info, and maybe if you are lucky you will get to a document explaining it. Or maybe it uses a standardized interface, so you can look at the standard. In the end, the linux driver path is really the last hope..

Comment: @frarugi87 still wondering how those people on youtube did it, but anyeays i should look for a datasheet of my camera then? Even if I manage to get that I still won't get how to get it working, what is the next step in learning all this. I mean I believe i got to know all the basics around the arduino

Comment: If you have a working driver for linux/windows then you can sometimes sniff the interface and get at the protocol, and from there make your own driver for whatever platform.  That is how a number of closed protocols are figured out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to fire the camera shutter at predetermined intervals? - [Wikipedia - Intervalometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervalometer)

Depending on the camera it may have an interface on the side which if you close it (possibly meaning, connecting it to ground) then it will take a photo.

A while ago I had a [project to take freeze-frame photographs](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11671) which involved having the Arduino trigger the camera flash.

I had to purchase a suitable interface cable, get to the bare wires, and connect them to an output pin. Then a simple program "closed" the connection and fired the flash when required.

In your case you could do a similar thing, if the camera supports it. By "supports it" I mean an electrical shutter interface. I think this is becoming increasingly common. It is certainly more likely than some sort of USB interface to fire the shutter.